# how to insert facebook login data into two table using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook-login

controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Test extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct() 
    {
        parent :: __construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url', 'captcha', 'email', 'html'));
        $this->load->library('facebook');
        $this->load->model('user');
    }
    public function login()
    {
        $userData = array();
        if($this->facebook->is_authenticated())
        {
            $userProfile = $this->facebook->request('get', '/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,locale,picture');
            $userData['oauth_provider'] = 'facebook';
            $userData['oauth_uid'] = $userProfile['id'];
            $userData['first_name'] = $userProfile['first_name'];
            $userData['last_name'] = $userProfile['last_name'];
            $userData['email'] = $userProfile['email'];
            $userData['gender'] = $userProfile['gender'];
            $userData['locale'] = $userProfile['locale'];
            $userData['profile_url'] = 'https://www.facebook.com/'.$userProfile['id'];
            $userData['picture_url'] = $userProfile['picture']['data']['url'];
            $userID = $this->user->checkUser($userData);
            if(!empty($userID)){
                $data['userData'] = $userData;
                $this->session->set_userdata('userData',$userData);
            } else {
               $data['userData'] = array();
            }
            $data['logoutUrl'] = $this->facebook->logout_url();
        }
        else
        {
            $fbuser = '';
            $data['authUrl'] =  $this->facebook->login_url();
        }
        $data['student_id'] = $this->session->userdata('student_id');
        $this->load->view('header',$data);
        $this->load->view('login',$data);
    }
}
```

view:login.php

```
<?php
    if(!empty($authUrl)) 
    {
        echo '<a href="'.$authUrl.'"><img src="'.base_url().'assets/images/flogin.png" alt="collegescan facebook login" style="width: 200px;"/></a>';
    }
    else
    {
?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="welcome_txt">Welcome <b><?php echo $userData['first_name']; ?></b></div>
    <div class="fb_box">
        <p><b>Logout from <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Facebook</a></b></p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php 
    } 
?>
```

models:User.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class User extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct() 
    {
        $this->tableName = 'users';
        $this->primaryKey = 'id';
    }
    public function checkUser($data = array())
    {
        $this->db->select($this->primaryKey);
        $this->db->from($this->tableName);
        $this->db->where(array('oauth_provider'=>$data['oauth_provider'],'oauth_uid'=>$data['oauth_uid']));
        $prevQuery = $this->db->get();
        $prevCheck = $prevQuery->num_rows();

        if($prevCheck > 0)
        {
            $prevResult = $prevQuery->row_array();
            $data['modified'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $update = $this->db->update($this->tableName,$data,array('id'=>$prevResult['id']));
            $userID = $prevResult['id'];
        }
        else
        {
            $data['created'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $data['modified'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $insert = $this->db->insert($this->tableName,$data);
            $insert = $this->db->insert('students',$data);
            $userID = $this->db->insert_id();
            $data = array(
                        'firstname' => $userProfile['first_name'],
                        'lastname' => $userProfile['last_name'],
                        'email' => $userProfile['email'] 
                    );
            $this->db->insert('students', $data);
        }
        return $userID?$userID:FALSE;
    }
}
```

In this code I have created facebook login in codeigniter it work perfectly and facebook login data insert in users table but now I want to insert only firstname,lastname and email in students table which is not inserted yet. So, How can I do this ?Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: What have you tried to achieve that?

Comment: just look at my model @MaciejJureczko

Comment: can anybody help me pls

Comment: In model you have declare
`$data = array(
                        'firstname' => $userProfile['first_name'],
                        'lastname' => $userProfile['last_name'],
                        'email' => $userProfile['email'] 
                    );
            $this->db->insert('students', $data); `
but i haven't found $userProfile variable you defined